# Load javascript animation ONLY when entire site (images) loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm building this hotsite that relies heavily on 'heavy' images and animations.

It has some "Curtains" covering all the site, then i want to open these curtains (animate, already coded it), but only when all my site (specially images) is loaded.

Would also like to create a simple loader (no progress at all, just say "loading");

UPDATE:

```
$.ready(function() {
            $("#loading").fadeOut();
            $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({ width: '374px', left: '-60px' }, 6200);
            $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({ width: '374px', right: '-60px' }, 6200);

            $(".leftback").stop().animate({ width: '60px' }, 6500);
            $(".rightback").stop().animate({ width: '60px' }, 6500);

    });
```

Comment: window.onload = function() {}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using

```
window.onload = function() {
    // initialize site
};
```

Will work. It fires once everything embedded into the site (HTML, CSS, images...) has finished loading.

You will then need to hide your website content while it loads. If you place everything within a DIV, you can toggle the visibility of it with "visibility: hidden". You should not use "display: none", as with some browsers (if I can remember correctly, Opera), they won't load content that has no display value.

You should then be able to place a DIV containing your "Loading" content at the top of the page, then simply either toggle off the display of it, or remove it from the DOM once the page is loaded.

---

As a side note, you should not use the jQuery.ready() function, as pointed out by RobG, as this only waits for the DOM to load, and not the images.

Comment: That looks like it's working. I'll test when it's online. Now, is there any way I can load FIRST the curtains + loader and just then start loading the rest of the content?

Answer (score 2):

try combining jQuery`s  [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var images = $('img');
    var loadedImgs = [];
    images.each(function()
    {        
        $(this).load(function() //image load callback
        {        
            loadedImgs.push('');
        });
        // we are interested only if the images is loaded,
        // so we need to place something in the loadedImgs array;
    });
    var interval = setInterval(function()
    {
        if(loadedImg.length == loadedImgs.length)
        {
            clearInterval(interval);
           //your code here ... images were loaded !!!
        }
    },10);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your handlers inside [`window.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). This is triggered only after the page is fully loaded, including graphics.

```
$(window).load()
```

Comment: Strictly, *load* event listeners should be attached to the *body* element, but I don't know of where attaching to *window* will fail.

Comment: @RobG, Interesting how the jQuery documentation on `load` describes `$(window).load()` specifically. You might want to take a look.

Comment: the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) doesn't tell you anything about what the code is actually doing (please include links if you are going to reference them.). The above will attach a load listener to the `window` object, which jQuery does on *every* call to `$(<someFn>)` but in this case it is depending upon it. Of course if you try `$('body')load(...)` it fails, but that's jQuery.

Comment: That's isn't jQuery, that's DOM. The load event is a window thing, but since you don't have a `<window>` element, the intrinsic event handler  attribute gets shunted to the body element.

Comment: @RobG: I actually referenced a link to the jQuery API in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prototype's Event.observe like

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function()
    {
        //add javascript script tags to the document here
    }
```

Function in Event.observe will be called only after all the images in the DOM are loaded.

Comment: The question is tagged jQuery, there is absolutely not reason to use another chunky library for this.

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // javascript code will be executed only after the whole dom is loaded
}
```

With Jquery:

```
$.ready(function(){
    // some code
});
```

Comment: From the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29): `...$(document).ready() function. Everything inside it will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded`, wherese the OP seems to be after the load event. So **don't** use `jQuery.ready()`.

Comment: I did this (look update with code) but it just goes animating + loading at the same time

Comment: @Vitor Reis Try use window.onload = function(){}

Comment: That looks like it's working. I'll test when it's online. Now, is there any way I can load FIRST the curtains + loader and just then start loading the rest of the content?